# What compression method are Adobe Acrobat using in PDF Barcodes?

Tags: pdf, compression, adobe, qr-code, barcode

I have created a PDF through Adobe Acrobat Pro. In that PDF I use a barcode to gather all the data from the form so that I can scan even a printed copy of the PDF. The problem is that it takes up way to much space on the form so I tried the compression built-in to Adobe Acrobat Pro (Compress data before Encoding to Barcode) which, as expected, shrinks the barcode significantly. The only problem is that I can't find out what compression method they are using so that I can decompress the data back to its original form.

I started building a C# application that decodes the barcode using ZXing.NET.
Without the compression I can clearly see the data and everything is read correctly but if I compress the same barcode and scan it I can't find a way to decompress it. I have used different encodings (UTF-8, Latin1, Unicode, ASCII) and different Decompression methods (Deflate, Gzip, Zip) but none of them seems to be able to decompress the data back into readable data.

Does anyone know what decompression method I should be using? I have searched the adobe help pages but came up empty handed.